# ZF: view variable definition for layout

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, layout, controller

I have some controller Index.
There I defined variable:

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
      function IndexController()
      {
           $this->view->some_val = 100;
      }
}
```

And the layout is like this:

```
<html>
<p><?= $this->some_val; ?></p>
<?= $this->getLayout()->content; ?>
</html>
```

But in th this case I get NULL instead of 100. I tried to define it in preDispatch function but result is the same. 
Could anybody help pls? 
Thanks to all in advance

Comment: BTW: you should not use the short php tags: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: From my experience, this should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One one would be as @Yanick Rochon wrote. Another way would be to assing variables directly to your layout(), e.g.

```
class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
      function IndexController()
      {
           $this->view->layout()->some_val = 100;
      }
}
```

Then in your layout;

```
<p><?= $this->layout()->some_val; ?></p>
```

Comment: Could you be so kind to explain what is the difference between assigning variables to the View instance and to the the Layout? Here's my question here about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396521/what-is-layout-and-what-is-view-in-zf-when-and-whose-variables-should-i-use-and . Kindly ask you to explain. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to save a reusable variable, use the `placeholder` view helper

```
public function indexAction() {
    $this->view->placeholder('some_value')->set(100);
}
```

and in any view script, or layout

```
echo $this->placeholder('some_value')->getValue();   // -> 100
```