# What is Layout and what is View in ZF? When and whose variables should I use and why?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I can't understand when to use `Layout`'s variables and when to use `View`'s variables to get page segments on the page. Here is the picture form their `Layout` package tutorial (`$this` means the `View` instance everywhere):
[image]

Why `Navigation`, `Content` and `Sidebar` segments are got as `Layout` variables?

```
$this->layout()->nav;
```

But `HeadTitle`, `HeadScript`, `HeadStylesheet` are got straightly from View?

```
$this->headTitle(); // I know that this is a placeholder view helper. 
                    // But this segment of the page logically belongs to Layout.
                    // and it has to be called smth like view->layout->placeholder
```

And why `Header` and `Footer` are from some `partial` method of the `View` but not `Layout`'s properties?

```
$this->partial('header.phtml');
```

I've tried to change them and both ways work fine:

```
echo $this->nav; // I assigned navigation segment script to the View and it works;
```

I tried to assign `Footer` segment script to the `Layout` and it also works:

```
$layout->footer = $footer;
echo $this->layout()->footer;  // it also works, it's displayed on the page
```

Any of the ways may be applied to any variable on the page. For example in `Navigation` segment I have a lot of variables to display and I can output them using both ways - one variable as `Layout`'s property, another one sa `View`'s property.

So what is the rule to use them right way? When should I use `View`'s variables and when `Layout`'s ones?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that this isn't very clear from the documentation, and I don't think `$this->layout()->nav` is explained at all. A few points that might help:

- `$this->layout()` is actually a call to the layout view helper, which returns the current instance of `Zend_Layout`.
- `Zend_Layout` registers its own placeholder helper (with the key 'Zend_Layout'), and by default creates a 'content' variable in this.
- the `Zend_Layout` class has a magic `__get()` method which proxies any member variable calls over to its registered placeholder container. So calling `$this->layout()->content` is another way of writing `$this->placeholder('Zend_Layout')->content`
- the `Zend_Layout` class also has a magic `__set()` method that proxies stored data to the placeholder class. So `$layout->footer = 'foo'` is the same as calling `$this->placeholder('Zend_Layout')->footer = 'foo' in the view`

With that in mind:

> Why Navigation, Content and Sidebar segments are got as Layout variables?

As these are accessing data stored in `Zend_Layout`'s placeholder. You could also use `$this->placeholder('Zend_Layout')->content`

> But HeadTitle, HeadScript, HeadStylesheet are got straightly from View?

These are view helpers.

> And why Header and Footer are from some partial method of the View but not Layout's properties?

This is the standard way of accessing content from other templates.

In general, assume that using the view object is the correct way to access the data. Use the layout object/helper only if you know the data is in the layout placeholder.

The advantage of using placeholders over partials is that you can access and modify them in several different places, including in the view itself. For example say you had a sidebar which is stored in a partial. If you were to store this in the Zend_Layout placeholder instead (for example in a controller plugin), you can then override this for certain actions in the controller:

```
public function someAction()
{
    $this->view->layout()->sidebar = 'Some other sidebar content';
}
```

or in the view script itself:

```
<?php $this->layout()->sidebar = 'Content for this page only'; ?>
```